# onkeydown responde a la tecla anterior, por qué?

Tags: javascript

Muy buenas!
 Tengo un input que quiero que solo reciba números y que, cuando reciba una  letra, borre el último caracter. Es decir, la letra...

Pues bien, en mi pobre código, cada vez que presiono una tecla se almacena en la variable "alumno" la tecla que presioné anteriormente. No sé si me explico bien...    Lo que quiero decir es que si he presionado 1 y 2 solo se almacena 1 y, si presiono de nuevo el nº 3, aparecería almacenado solo 1 y 2

Por qué puede ser esto?

```
<input type="text" id="texto" placeholder="ID del alumno">
<script>
    function tecla(event){
        var codigo = event.which || event.keyCode;
        var alumno = document.getElementById("texto").value;
        if(codigo <= 47 || codigo >= 58){
            var largo = alumno.length;
            texto.textContent = alumno.substring(0,largo - 1);
            console.log(alumno);
        }
    }

    texto.onkeydown = tecla;
</script>
```

Mucísimas gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que seleccionas el texto `onkeydown` cuando todavia no se a insertado el ultimo caracter.  Si cambias el handler a `onkeyup` tu codigo funciona bien:

```html
<input type="text" id="texto" placeholder="ID del alumno">
<script>
    function tecla(event){
        var codigo = event.which || event.keyCode;
        var alumno = document.getElementById("texto").value;
        
        if(codigo <= 47 || codigo >= 58){
            var largo = alumno.length;
            texto.textContent = alumno.substring(0,largo - 1);
            console.log(alumno);
        }
    }

    texto.onkeyup = tecla;
</script>
```

Comment: Gracias @alanfcm!

Muy bien explicado

Answer (score 1):

En vez de utilizar el evento `onkeydown` utiliza `onkeyup`:

```
texto.onkeyup = tecla;
```

`onkeyup` no se dispara hasta que sueltas la tecla.